# Entity framework : Bring a list of tables after comparing with other table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Good day,

I have a diagram with 5 tables. 
[image: my diagram]

As you can see, I have a category table and medical studies with details.
Also two similar tables  : OtherStudy and OtherMedicalStudyDetails.
These tables also have some foreing keys that come from other tables that are not included in this diagram.
For the sake of simplicity I provided a database diagram that does not look good but makes it simpler to explain my problem (somebody could tell me I should use just the medicalStudy and medicalStudy details tables and do not use the other two, but I would like to keep the diagram like this please).

What I am trying to do is, after adding (using c# entityframework) a medicalStudy with its MedicalStudyDetails, compare both detail tables and bring a list of all "OtherStudy" where `(MedicalStudyDetails.FK_otherTable==OtherMedicalStudyDetails.FK_otherTable&& MedicalStudyDetails.FK_anotherTable==OtherMedicalStudyDetails.FK_anotherTable)`.
. Note that this compairson should be done foreach MedicalStudyDetails added.

is there a way to bring the mentioned list using a sintax like this?

```
 var otherStudy= _dbContext.MedicalStudyDetails.Include(...)
            .Where(...)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: do you know what an inner join is?

Comment: Which part of the LINQ statement is unclear to you? You're not asking how to use `Include` or `Where`, do you? That would be rather trivial. Off-topic but important: I don't understand your data model (even though it's contrived). You don't need two (or more) sets of identical tables. All studies can be stored in `Study` and `StudyDetails` tables only.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you need a multiple clause inner join to achive this??

```
from msd in _dbContext.MedicalStudyDetails
join omsd in _dbContext.OtherMedicalStudyDetails on 
    new {msd.FK_otherTable, msd.FK_anotherTable} equals new { omsd.FK_otherTable, omsd.FK_anotherTable}
where ...
select ...
```